# Create abstract class with generic Type in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I am so confused, I've been searching how kotlin generics work, but I don't get it at all.

Basically, I have `BaseAnimalDetail` class, which is being used with some classes extending `Animal` class. At the moment, there are a lot of `when` in the `BaseAnimalDetail` class, so my goal is to avoid all those `when`, just extending `BaseAnimalDetail whenever I need, for each class that extends` Animal`

```
open class BaseAnimalDetail<T : Animal?> : LinearLayout{
    private var animal: T? = null
    
    fun setAnimal(animal:T){
        this.animal = animal
    }

    private fun play() {
        when(animal){
           is Horse -> playWithHorse...
           is Dog -> playWithDog...
           is Cat -> playWithCat...
        }
        animal?.let { it.play() } //this is not working but animal?.play works fine, WHY?
    }
    ...More code
}
```

As you can see, `when` is super ugly, so I would like to make `BaseAnimalDetail` abstract and implement it like I said.

Code above is just an example, but it would help me to understand how generics work in Kotlin. It's mandatory for me to have the T var in the base class

Furthermore, WHY `animal?.let { it.play() }` does not compile?

Comment: Can you post your Animal class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you're describing, you want each type of Animal to have its own BaseAnimalDetail subclass to go with it. So you should make BaseAnimalDetail an abstract class, and then you can create subclasses for each Animal.

By the way, since Kotlin has properties, it is redundant to make `animal` private and have a setter function.

```
abstract class BaseAnimalDetail<T : Animal> {
    var animal: T? = null
    abstract fun play()
}

class CatDetail: BaseAnimalDetail<Cat>(){
    override fun play() {
        println("toss yarn to $animal")
    }
}
```

But if all these different functions are different for each type of Animal, it sounds to me like you shouldn't have a separate BaseAnimalDetail class at all, and its functionality should just be in the various Animal classes. Alternatively, if there are certain behaviors that some animals share, you can create various behavior classes that can be added to the Animal class (composition design strategty).

Comment: I don't understand why you created that constructor. I have a setAnimal method to set it when I need. And it's mandatory for me to have the var animal T to use it from BaseAnimalDetail when needed

Comment: The property doesn't have to be in the constructor (that's just for convenience), but `setAnimal` is completely redundant in Kotlin because `animal` is a property. It has an implied getter and setter with a backing field. You can customize the setter at the declaration site later without changing any signatures, just like with a Java setter.

Comment: I updated it to pull the property out of the constructor. It's not really relevant to what you were asking, though, is it?

Comment: It just occurred to me maybe you weren't aware that properties in the constructor are just as valid as properties outside the constructor. They are not private to the constructor, but are available to use for the lifetime of the object, just like other properties. Putting them in the constructor makes it convenient to set them while you instantiate the class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understand u correctly, but what u could do is as u said - transform your `BaseAnimalDetail` to abstract class with abstract fun `fun play()` and let `Animal` class to extend `BaseAnimalDetail` or let ur `Horse`, `Dog` extend it directly.

```kotlin
abstract class BaseAnimalDetail {
    abstract fun play()
}

open class Animal : BaseAnimalDetail() {
    override fun play() = Unit
}

class Horse : Animal() {

    override fun play() {
        playWithHorse()
    }

    private fun playWithHorse() {}
}

class Dog : BaseAnimalDetail() {

    override fun play() {
        playWithDog()
    }

    private fun playWithDog() {}
}
```

Also "whenever I need" could be provided by an interface since our goal is to provide a function and there is no deeper logic there.

Comment: It's mandatory for me to have the var animal T to use it from BaseAnimalDetail when needed, furthermore, do you know why animal?.let { it.play() } does not compile?
thanks

Comment: What is the error for `animal?.let { it.play() }`? Looks like it should work fine, although it's just a verbose way of writing `animal?.play()`.

Comment: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: 
required:
Animal
found:
T!

Comment: I think you've removed too much context of what's going on around it for us to see the problem. What you have above works fine as is: https://pl.kotl.in/hvAe2OnNy

Comment: This error would occur if the `play` function has a return type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why do you need generics for this, here is my implementation

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract fun play()
}

class Horse : Animal() {
    override fun play() {
        playWithHorse()
    }
    private fun playWithHorse() {}
}

class Dog : Animal() {
    override fun play() {
        playWithDog()
    }
    private fun playWithDog() {}
}


open class BaseAnimalDetail(var animal: Animal?=null) {
    private fun play() {
       animal?.play()
    }
}

class HorseDetail(var horse: Horse? = null): BaseAnimalDetail(horse){

}
```

You can remove `play` func from BaseAnimalDetail, instead directly call `horse?.play()` too.

Comment: My code is just an example of something more complex I need, I need to have a variable in BaseAnimalDetail (not in the constructor). Thanks

Comment: It is default argument so you don't need to pass the value in constructor.

Comment: Generics are needed if you want to retrieve `animal` and have it automatically treated as the known subtype by the compiler.